# Dapper and Subclasses

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm working with an existing EF data model that includes subclassed objects.  That works fine when working with individual objects, but is quite slow when loading a large number of objects for analysis.

I started exploring [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) as an alternative for populating POCO objects used for read-only analysis.

The trouble is, I can't see any means to correctly handle an object hierarchy.

If I have

```
class MyBase
{
}

class MyDerived1 : MyBase
{
}

class MyDerived2 : MyBase
{
}
```

Dapper correctly populates a list of `MyBase`

```
var mine = conn.Query<MyBase>("SELECT * from MyTable");
```

The Multimap capability doesn't seem to solve the problem (or am I missing something?).

Is there a way to solve this, short of making one round-trip to the database for each subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public class MyBase
    {
        public String BaseProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDerived1 : MyBase
    {
        public String Derived1Prop { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDerived2 : MyBase
    {
        public String Derived2Prop { get; set; }
    }
```

Multimapping or a dynamic mapping should do the trick.

MM:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Table";

var res = conn.Query<MyBase, MyDerived1, MyDerived2, Tuple<MyBase, MyDerived1, MyDerived2>>(query, (b, d1, d2) => Tuple.Create(b, d1, d2), splitOn: "Derived1Id,Derived2Id");
```

[image]

The dynamic mapping is also very cool and probably more flexible in your case (Thanks @Sam!)

```
var res = conn.Query<dynamic>(query).Select(x => new Tuple<MyBase, MyDerived1, MyDerived2>(new MyBase() { BaseProp = x.BaseProp },
                                                                                                           new MyDerived1() { Derived1Prop = x.Derived1Prop },
                                                                                                           new MyDerived2() { Derived2Prop = x.Derived2Prop }));
```

Comment: I can see why that would help with only one subclass of MyBase, but I have multiple subclasses in the same table (default Entity Framework storage).  I could certainly repeat that approach once for each subclass, with a WHERE clause in the Descriminator column, but that results in N round-trips to the DB for N subclasses.

Comment: @EricJ. you can always map it to dynamic and then transform to specific entities ... or run 2 queries in a grid

Comment: The dynamic mapping looks like it will solve the problem (I really don't want to run two queries).  Thanks!